# How to display multiple selected values in ion select?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using developing an PWA with Ionic 4. while using ion-select for selecting multiple values like this.

```
<div class="form-group">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="briefcase"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label floating color="primary">Business Unit *</ion-label>
    <ion-select multiple="true" placeholder="Select Business" (ionChange)="onBuSelectChange($event)"
      formControlName="businessUnit" class="form-control"
      [ngClass]="{'is-valid' : submitted && f.businessUnit.errors}">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let unit of listBusinessUnit" [value]="unit.ID">
        {{unit.BusinessUnitDesc}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
    <h1 *ngIf="submitted && f.businessUnit.errors && f.businessUnit.errors.required" floating>*</h1>
  </ion-item>

</div>
```

I am getting following output where user is only able to see text of first selected value of ion-options.

[image]

I tried overriding css with the following with no success.

```
.select-text {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 190px;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre-line;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this on your css, this work for me.

```
ion-select::part(text) {
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

you can refer to this :

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#styling-select-element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is late, but I was facing the same problem in my project, The selected options didn't fit inside select item. 
The way I was able to solve it is creating an additional element just to show the results (I use popover interface for ion-select element). I know this is not quite a solution, but still it works and looks decent. Maybe someone else can suggest a better way, I would prefer cleaner solution, but for now this is the only way I could handle this.
This is my solution based on your example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon slot="start" name="briefcase"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label floating color="primary">Business Unit *</ion-label>

    // I render select hidden
    <ion-select multiple="true" placeholder="Select Business" formControlName="businessUnit" interface="popover" #select>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let unit of listBusinessUnit" [value]="unit.ID">
        {{unit.BusinessUnitDesc}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>

    // And this is visualization part. I chose chips for values visualization as it looks nicer
    <ion-item lines="none" (click)="select.open()"> // <- here I use open() function to trigger open command of select
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="caret-down-outline" class="attributi__icon"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label color="tertiary" class="attributi__label">Business units</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let unit of listBusinessUnit">
      // here I use formControlgetter to get the current value ofselect and show only the selected items
      <ion-chip *ngIf="businessUnit.value.includes(unit.id)" color="dark" outline="true">{{unit.BusinessUnitDesc}}</ion-chip>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

And this is the result, but on my project where I use it.
(I don't have enought reputation to post images so here are the links)

[Here are the chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UDSS.png)
[And here is select popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sjlA.png)

Comment: Hello @Olga Demina, Thanks for taking the initiative to this implementation approach, Can I have the typescript implementation for this method as this isn't working in ionic 6.16.3